# Output FALSE instead of error in R

Tags: r, error-handling, matrix

What I would like to do is test whether a matrix is positive definite using the command chol() in R. However, if the chol() command produces an error I would like it to output false rather than producing an error and stopping the code from running. Is there an easy way to do this? I have been messing around with the command try() but it still gives me an error.
For example, if I have the matrix:

```
mat=matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,5,5,5),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=F)
try(chol(mat))
```

this still produces an error "Error in chol.default(mat) : 
the leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite."

How can I get this to produce FALSE instead of this error?

Comment: I don't think that your test using a chol decomposition is a good idea. I mean, what happens in your case if chol() fails for other reasons?!

Comment: I do have to compute the cholesky anyways so even if it does fail for some other reason I still want it to produce FALSE. Thank you for bringing up this concern though, that is a very valid point.

Comment: Okay, I see your point, error handling is always a good idea! I just try to remember, isn't it so that for pd matrices the eigenvalues are larger than 0 as well? Could a test like `sum(eigen(mat)$values>0)` give you an additional test for PD, just to catch those cases where the `chol()` fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `tryCatch`, and define a handler to use in the event of an error:

```
tryCatch(chol(mat), error=function(e) FALSE)
```